# How to override the properties file value through command line arguments?

Tags: java, parsing, command-line, properties, command-line-arguments

I have a property file which is like this -

```
hostName=machineA.domain.host.com
emailFrom=tester@host.com
emailTo=world@host.com
emailCc=hello@host.com
```

And now I am reading the above property file from my Java program as -

```
public class FileReaderTask {
    private static String hostName;
    private static String emailFrom;
    private static String emailTo;
    private static String emailCc;

    private static final String configFileName = "config.properties";
    private static final Properties prop = new Properties();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readConfig(arguments);
    }

    private static void readConfig(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(args) && args.length != 0) {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
        } else {
            prop.load(FileReaderTask.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFileName));
        }

        hostName = prop.getProperty("hostName").trim();         
        emailFrom = prop.getProperty("emailFrom").trim();
        emailTo = prop.getProperty("emailTo").trim();
        emailCc = prop.getProperty("emailCc").trim();
    }
}
```

Most of the time, I will be running my above program through command line as a runnable jar like this -

```
java -jar abc.jar config.properties
```

**My questions are -**

- Is there any way we can override the above attributes in the property file through command line without touching the file if needed? Since I don't want to modify my config.properties file always whenever I need to change any attributes value? Is this possible to do?

Something like this should override the hostName value in the file?

```
java -jar abc.jar config.properties hostName=machineB.domain.host.com
```

- And also, is there any way to add `--help` while running the `abc.jar` that can tell us more about how to run the jar file and what does each property means and how to use them? I have seen `--help` while running most of the C++ executable or Unix stuff so not sure how we can do the same thing in Java?

Do I need to use CommandLine parser for this in Java to achieve both of the things?

Comment: That's when you make use of the `String[] args` variable passed to `public static void main` method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for suggestion. Can you provide an example how would I do this? I also need to add `--help` functionality by which anyone can get to know how to run this jar and what are the various config parameters and what do they mean in general? Do we need to use any command line parser like JCommander?

Comment: You could do it manually or use a library like that. The decision is up to you (or your team).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only things you will have on your commandline are things like: `hostName=machineB.domain.host.com` and not any other types of arguments, then you can simplify your commandline handling quite a lot:

First, join all the command-line args with newlines as if they were a new config file:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String arg : args) {
    sb.append(arg).append("\n");
}
String commandlineProperties = sb.toString();
```

now, you have two property sources, your file, and this string. You can load them both in to a single Properties instance, with one version overwriting the other:

```
if (...the config file exists...) {
    try (FileReader fromFile = new FileReader("config.properties")) {
        prop.load(fromFile);
    }
}

if (!commandlineProperties.isEmpty()) {
    // read, and overwrite, properties from the commandline...
    prop.load(new StringReader(commandlineProperties));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot rolfl for the help. What about my second question? How would I approach that one. Any idea?

Comment: CommandLine is commonly used for that. I have (years ago) written my own that the company I work for owns, so I can't share. See Apache CLI here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/